# Undefined Variable from import when using a .pyd library through a helper module

Tags: python, import, pylint

I have the following files: (Note that library is a pyd file -- it's an external vendor library that is on sys.path but not in PYTHONPATH)

```
library.pyd
library_helper.py
one.py
two.py
```

Assume that `library.pyd` has a method `getName()`.

**one.py**

```
import library #@UnresolvedImport
...  
print library.getName()
```

I don't have any `lint` errors here. The code runs fine.

But if I do this:

**library_helper.py**

```
import library #@UnresolvedImport
```

**two.py**

```
from library_helper import library
...
print library.getName()
```

`two.py` gives a `lint` error when calling `library.getName()`, `"Undefined variable from import: getName."` The code still runs fine, it just doesn't seem to like the fact that I am going through library_helper.

I'm confused why this causes a problem. My research so far points to something related to the library.pyd doing some import hook that allows me to do getName() without errors, but I do not know how I could go about making this work.

Advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this just about lint, or does the import in two.py not work?

Comment: The import in two.py works. The code runs fine. It just doesn't seem to 'respect' the lint suppression the same way the call in one.py does.